# osascript syntax error "Expected expression but found end of line. (-2741)"

Tags: bash, syntax-error, applescript, osascript

I am writing a bash script that utilizes AppleScript that disables the microphone and camera, and then clicks the "Join now" button on the google meet webpage. The portion that disables the microphone and camera works perfectly, but I am running into issues with the part of the script that is meant to click the join button. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript <<EOF

tell application "System Events"

    delay 4

    key code 14 using command down 
    delay 1 

    key code 2 using command down
    delay 1 

end tell

EOF

#the following is not working- 

osascript <<EOF

tell application "brave" 
  tell active tab of window 1 to - 
  execute JavaScript "document.getElementById('Join now')[0].click();" 
end tell 

EOF
```

When the second part of the script tries to execute, I get this error:

> 62:63: syntax error: Expected expression but found end of line. (-2741)

How do I fix this error and get the script to execute properly (click the button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a proper *line continuation character* after `to`:

```
tell active tab of window 1 to -
```

Use: `¬`, e.g.:

```
tell active tab of window 1 to ¬
```

The *line continuation character* can be created by typing <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in **Script Editor**.

If it still throws an error, then put it all on one line, e.g.:

```
tell active tab of window 1 to execute JavaScript "document.getElementById('Join now')[0].click();"
```